# How to transfer minecraft pocket edition world between iPads?

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My daughter has built a minecraft world on our iPad. As of Christmas 2013 she has an iPad mini of her own. Is there any way to transfer her world from the old machine?

Even better...is there any way to synchronise the 2 machines?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have a computer you can download a program called iExplorer.
Once you do that plug the iPad (not mini) into the computer via USB Connector that comes with any Apple device. Make sure you don't have any apps running on the iPad, and when the time comes, make sure you don't have anything open on the iPad mini as well.

1. Open iExplorer and your iPad should appear, look at the left hand side of the screen and a file labeled `applications` will appear.
2. Click it. Open the file labeled `Minecraft PE`.
3. Click on `Documents`, then `Games`, then `Com.Mojang` then `minecraftWorlds`.
4. Open that file and drag all the files inside it to your desktop. Once it is complete, unplug the device.
5. Plug in the iPad mini and do everything you just did, but this time, drag all of the files from your desktop into the `minecraftworlds` folder.
6. Unplug the iPad mini and navigate to wherever minecraft PE is on your iPad mini.
7. Open the app and all of your old worlds will be there!

Comment: Downloaded iExplorer to Windows. Open it -> Continue in Demo mode -> Apps -> Minecraft PE -> Documents -> games -> com.mojang -> mineCraftWorlds. Got the files. Looks like the demo version lasts 30 days so I may revert to iFunBox after that +1 and accepted for comprehensive description

Comment: Using this method could you import a PE world to a PC versions and Vice Versa

Comment: You can accomplish this with just the iBrowse app, which is a simpler version of iExplorer that is free and doesn't require Quicktime. http://www.ibrowseapp.com/

Comment: @Flaunting - no, PC and PE versions are not interchangable - the game itself (minecraft) is a completely different game under the hood and the save games are incompatible.

Comment: Link to download iExplorer: https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

Comment: I have been able to do the same through iTunes itself, through "File Sharing".  Select Minecraft, then under "Minecraft Documents", select "games" and "Save to.."

Comment: @wrschneider How did you then import those saved worlds to the other ios device?

Comment: Windows 10
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the version, I only know how to create a multiplayer world, and have the other user join and then save the world.

[This page](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1464865-any-way-to-transfer-saves-from-one-phone-to-another/) has some information specifically post #9:

> download ifunbox, then open application documents, minecraft, and copy the documents folder, that are the saves, put the saves into the other iphone (you dont need jailbreak)

Comment: Post #9 suggests installing iFunBox (http://www.i-funbox.com/) on a computer then browse into the devices to get the files and copy them just as you would with Windows Explorer. It works so +1. Accepted the other answer because iExplorer also works and the answer is comprehensive

Comment: Hi, this link no longer works. Can you either update it or remove this answer?  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe The link appears to be working fine for me?

Comment: @Wipqozn hmm, was a dead post last night - maybe the forum was undergoing maintenance or something. Anyway I looked at it to see if I could move some of the info into the post and don’t see a clear way to do that - maybe editing post #9 in would be sufficient to make it not a link only answer?

Comment: @Joe You need 2k to make edits, but you should be able to suggest an edit via the "edit" button near the bottom of the answer. I've gone ahead and edited in the post for you, though, because that was a good idea.