# How can I copy a Minecraft PE world to another device?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

For a while now, I have been working on a world on Pocket edition on my iPad. However, for my birthday, I got a new iPad that I can use instead. I tried inputing the seed for my world, but my house was gone. I still have access to my world on my old iPad, but I would like to transfer it to my new iPad. Any suggestions?

Comment: If possible find and directly copy your files from your old ipad to your new one. Seeds are world generation codes, as in, seeds hold the data for the game to recreate the same world, it has nothing to do with how you have CHANGED that world in any way after it was generated. What you need is your specific save files transferred, but I don't know how to access them on an iPad.

Comment: Your question has already been asked [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148549/how-to-transfer-minecraft-pocket-edition-world-between-ipads), and I am marking this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @Ender I think you need to be jailbroken to do that, which will void your warranty on the device, if you have one.