# Saving Minecraft worlds to transfer after iTunes backup

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My daughter's iPad has a cracked screen and is being replaced by Apple under AppleCare Plus. I have backed up the iPad Mini to iTunes and I planned on restoring the new iPad from this backup. However I am told that the Minecraft worlds she worked so hard on to create will not be restored this way. I need to know how to save those worlds in iTunes backup so it restores to the new iPad. Clear instruction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain if you can back this up with the iTunes back-up, but I know you can copy the world folder and paste it back afterwards.

- **Step 1 :** Press the "Recents" button on your device and swipe Minecraft to close it. This will completely close the game and stop it from running in the background.
- **Step 2 :** Download a File Manager app on your device, or connect it to computer. This will allow you to access the file system of your Android device.
  There are several free file explorers available on the Play Store. ES File Explorer is one of the most popular.
  If you connect your device via computer, you can navigate through the folders just like you would with Windows folders.
- **Step 3 :** Start the File Manager app on your device. You will see a list of folders on your device. You may have to open the "sdcard" folder to see all of your system folders, depending on your device.
  You don't need a file manager app if you connect your device to the computer.
- **Step 4 :** Open the games → .com.mojang → minecraftWorlds folder. If you are using your computer, connect your device and select it from the Computer window (Windows) or your desktop (OS X).
  This will display a list of folders labeled with all of your created worlds, both Creative and Survival.
- **Step 5 :** Open the folder for the Creative world you want to transfer. You should see a "level.dat" file.
- **Step 6 :** Copy the "level.dat" file.
  Android - Press and hold the "level.dat" file and select "Copy" from the menu that appears.
  Computer - Right-click on it and select "Copy".
- **Step 7 :** After the backup you go to the same folder and paste your copied files there. If your daughter(s) boots up minecraft again she should have her worlds again.

NOTE : This only saves the world, the player data might not be saved.

---

For iOS, as Pansy said in the comments. iOS devices dont allow you to access their files so you can't do the above steps unless you pay for software that allows you to access those files.

**Copy your worlds with PhoneView**

> PhoneView ($29.95 Mac) from ecamm, the makers of Printopia, is an
>   application that can access your iOS devices filesystem in order to
>   access the information stored on your device. This includes the
>   documents that are created by each app on your device. It just so
>   happens that for Minecraft PE, the world files are stored in a manner
>   that is easy to back up and restore. You do not need to jailbreak your
>   device in order to use PhoneView to back up and restore your Minecraft
>   PE worlds.

Source for IOS : [HERE](https://gigaom.com/2013/01/31/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-minecraft-worlds-before-updating-the-ios-app/)

Comment: iOS devices do not expose their filesystems unless they're jailbroken. The process you're describing will not help the OP since she's not using an Android device

Comment: Editted my answer, didnt know that IOS doesnt allow you to access the game files. Could you reconsider your vote?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) is highly spoken of, but I haven't tried it myself.  It lets you access the filesystem on iOS devices without jailbreaking, which means that you can manually copy off your world files and transfer them.

Comment: Your answer would be helpful if you'd include instructions on how to do it using that program.

Comment: [This very similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148549/how-to-transfer-minecraft-pocket-edition-world-between-ipads) includes instructions for doing it in a very similar (for-pay) program called iExplorer.  There's also a link the comments to a similar question on the Minecraft forums, also with instructions.  In short: Applications -> Minecraft PE -> Documents -> Games -> Com.Mojang.

Comment: I just used iFunBox to grab the Minecraft PE worldfile folders and put them on my PC. I haven't used them for a restore yet, but the files can definitely be accessed on and moved from an iPad.