# Does Xbox Live save Minecraft worlds?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, xbox-network

I'm considering deleting minecraft to free up space but I want to save all of my worlds. I was wondering if Xbox Live will save your worlds so that when you log back into Xbox live it pulls all of you worlds up.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/games/game-setup/cloud-save-games

It seems you can, On xbox 360:

> Step 1: Turn on Cloud Saved Games (for a console)
>
> From the Xbox Dashboard, go to Settings and then select System.
>   Select Storage, and then select Cloud Saved Games.
>   Select Enable Cloud Saved Games.
>
> Existing game saves: If you have an existing saved game that you want to store in the cloud, you can move the saved game to the cloud. Here’s how:
>   Sign in to your Xbox Live profile.
>   Go to Settings, and then select System.
>   Select Storage.
>   Select the storage device that contains the saved game that you want to move to the cloud.
>   Select Games.
>   Select the game with your saved game.
>   Select your saved game.
>   Select Move.
>   Select Cloud Saved Games.

Comment: Oh that would really help but I don't have an Xbox. Yeah I know I should have one but all I have is the old wii this my iPad is most advanced gaming system I have besides my computer  but thanks for your help

Comment: I mean that in a nice way

Comment: If it's your ipad, xbox live sadly won't be able to do anything about backing up your save. Your best bet is looking into something like this

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/196729/saving-minecraft-worlds-to-transfer-after-itunes-backup

Comment: That may allow you to backup your saves manually. However I suggest doing a fair bit of research before doing so if you're very concerned about the worlds. Hope I've helped a bit!