# Error when trying to transfer Minecraft worlds from iOS to PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to transfer my daughter's minecraft worlds from her iPad to our PC. I created a new folder on the desktop, navigated in to my Apps in iTunes, then at the bottom of the screen click minecraft. Then I select games and click Save To and browse to the new folder but it keeps giving me an error that the game save can not be transferred because the selected folder can not be found. The iPad and iTunes are both up to date with the latest version and I have tried to transfer the game saves to several different PCs.

Is it possible to transfer the iOS minecraft world to a PC version?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do. It looks like the answer to this question will solve your problem with a little modification:

[Transfer MineCraft world from iOS to iOS](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148549/how-to-transfer-minecraft-pocket-edition-world-between-ipads)

Once you have the iOS world save files on to your PC. Navigate to the .minecraft/saves/ folder location and copy the files in. I believe you will need the entire directory of the game save files from the iOS device.