# How can I copy a part of my minecraft world and put it into another world on Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have this world where I build everything, but lately I have been building in to another world. I only want to have one world, so I am asking if anybody knows how to transfer the things I built to a different world.

How can I copy part of one minecraft world to another?

If it makes a difference, I am playing on iPad.

Comment: Is it a test world or a proper one?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it works in MCPE but in the Java edition you can use a command to get a block that can save a structure. The command is "/give @s structure_block". Once you have done this you have to be in creative to export it but it will say something like Structure Block at the top, and on the left it will say 3D export, don't change that. The max size for saving is 32*32*32 and it will only make a template in your survival world, not instant build. So type in the XYZ coordinates of the build in the GUI. And when you are saving an loading the name MUST be the same or it will fail. Not sure if you understand this but I hope you did.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to transfer a world to another device, or another copy of Minecraft, that would be done with [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148549/how-to-transfer-minecraft-pocket-edition-world-between-ipads) answer. I don't believe transferring actual buildings would be possible. Your best bet would be to take the world into creative mode and build whatever you wanted from the other world, and then switch it back to survival.