# Minecraft PE Creation to share

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I created an epic village on PE and would love to share with anyone.  Is it possible to make it a seed or share file?  If so, how would I go about doing this?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you enlighten us as to what device you are playing on? The general theory is that you need to locate your world save folder, and zip the files, and then change for extension to .mcworld. But specifics differ according to device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS, there is already a guide [here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148549/how-to-transfer-minecraft-pocket-edition-world-between-ipads)

If you are using Android, install ES File Explorer and go to the games folder in your sdcard. Inside there, go to com.mojang then saves. Find the folder with your world name and copy it to the other device using Bluetooth or something else.

Answer (score -1):

To share a save file for minecraft PE on iOS (iPhone/iPod/iPad) you would have to jailbreak your device and install Cydia. Then in Cydia you can install an application called iFile which will allow you to import and export minecraft PE worlds.

Comment: If you want to add Android to your answer... the path to the saves on Android are, by default, accessible at `/sdcard/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds`. The world folders made by the game are normally weirdly named, but you can find what the world's name as shown in the world select screen by looking in each world folder's `levelname.txt` (it is a plain text file, but be careful when editing it as it may break you from loading the world, or cause Minecraft to crash).

Comment: Also, I forgot if you can still do it, but it might be possible (if it still works) without Jailbreaking the iOS device by connecting it to a computer with iTunes on it and making sure you have it in "storage" mode after the device syncs with your computer.

Answer (score -1):

It is extremely hard to do that, especially as you would have to jailbreak your device. Maybe try building it again on a server/LAN world.